Navigate from one LWC to another LWC to edit opportunity record and create a new record
unable to load data into target LWC
I have created a quick action LWC on Opportunity Record to pass recordID and onclick of it I have created lightning record edit form LWC to update the selected opportunity fields and create a new opportunity record
